# Equivalent of WaitForNonStaleResults()?

Tags: mongodb, ravendb

Having previously used RavenDB (2.5) as a NoSQL document store, I have started using MongoDB. In RavenDB there is a method `WaitForNonStaleResults` which avoids dirty reads by waiting for the index from which you want to read to achieve a non-stale state.

Is there an equivalent in MongoDB?

Comment: I think MongoDB doesn’t suffer with stale indexes. Curiously we are long time MongoDB users evaluating RavenDB as better alternative. Why did you move from RavenDB to MongoDB, any specific reason?

Comment: I can only talk about RavenDB 2.5 and 3.0. 2.5 especially suffered from the stale index problem. An update in some cases would cause the whole index to rebuild, which in some cases meant that a query would return zero results for a number of minutes. We never got to the bottom of it, although I should say that when the database was set up one of the Raven employees was with us for a week as a consultant. 3.0 also showed a significant lag in this respect. I'm sure that the latest version of RavenDB would be better but the issue with stale indexes was just one of the problems we encountered.